# Django Rest Framework - How to import image as JPEG and save it as base 64 using serializer?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Model:

```
class Item(models.Model):

   class Meta:
       db_table = 't_item'

   item_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to='item_images')
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
   updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.item_name
```

Serializer:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        # Fields you want to be returned or posted
        fields = ('item_name', 'image', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
```

In the web view form, I want to import an image in JPEG format, and when it is posted, I want it to be saved as Base 64 format in the location specified in 'upload_to'. Is this possible?

Comment: yes, you can do that either in the view, overriding how the model is saved, or in the model, overriding the save method. But why would you do that? The image will be automatically saved as jpeg file when you save your model. If you want the image to be saved also in a different format, you could hook into the model's `post_save` signal and create the base64 file.

Comment: I'm using a ViewSet for Django Rest Framework. I want to save it as base 64 instead of JPEG so that it is more efficient in file size

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

in serailizer.py

```
class Base64ImageField(serializers.ImageField):

    def to_internal_value(self, data):

        from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
        import base64
        import six
        import uuid

        # Check if this is a base64 string
        if isinstance(data, six.string_types):
            # Check if the base64 string is in the "data:" format
            if 'data:' in data and ';base64,' in data:
                # Break out the header from the base64 content
                header, data = data.split(';base64,')

            # Try to decode the file. Return validation error if it fails.
            try:
                decoded_file = base64.b64decode(data)
            except TypeError:
                self.fail('invalid_image')

            # Generate file name:
            file_name = str(uuid.uuid4())[:12] # 12 characters are more than enough.
            # Get the file name extension:
            file_extension = self.get_file_extension(file_name, decoded_file)

            complete_file_name = "%s.%s" % (file_name, file_extension, )

            data = ContentFile(decoded_file, name=complete_file_name)

        return super(Base64ImageField, self).to_internal_value(data)

    def get_file_extension(self, file_name, decoded_file):
        import imghdr
        extension = imghdr.what(file_name, decoded_file)
        extension = "jpg" if extension == "jpeg" else extension

        return extension

class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   image = Base64ImageField(required=True)
```

in your api view

```
class ImageSave(APIView):
   serializer_class = ItemSerializer
   def post(self):
      serializer_instance = 
      self.serializer_class(data=self.request.data)

      if serializer_instance.is_valid():
         serializer_instance.save()

      return Response({})
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

> Write save function of model and access the uploaded image over there
>   then encode it base64 and save to non editable base64Image field.

```
import os
import base64

def image_as_base64(image_file, format='png'):
    """
    :param `image_file` for the complete path of image.
    :param `format` is format for image, eg: `png` or `jpg`.
    """
    if not os.path.isfile(image_file):
        return None

    encoded_string = ''
    with open(image_file, 'rb') as img_f:
        encoded_string = base64.b64encode(img_f.read())
    return 'data:image/%s;base64,%s' % (format, encoded_string)


# Example Usage

from django import models
from django.conf import settings

class Post(models.Model):

    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d')

    def get_cover_base64(self):
        # settings.MEDIA_ROOT = '/path/to/env/projectname/media'
        return image_as_base64(settings.MEDIA_ROOT + self.cover.path)
```

Comment: Add some description with your answer with a docx link(If you have)

Comment: sorry here is the details.

Comment: you should also pass the original arguments to the `super().save()` method. Using `**kwargs` would be easier.

Comment: I got an error: Got a `TypeError` when calling `Item.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `Item.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the ItemSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.

Comment: You can save that base64 image to defferent field.

Comment: I'm still getting the error even if I saved it in  another field base64image

Comment: let me execute it